# What extra packages are needed by Amarok to transcode to MP3?

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, mp3, amarok, transcode

I'm using Amarok 2.6.0, on KDE version 4.9.3, on Kubuntu 12.04. I would like to be able to copy my music onto my MP3 player (in this case, my iPhone 3), but to transcode the tracks as I copy them over. However, when I right-click on the selected track, and choose "Copy to Collection" and select my iPhone, the option to transcode to MP3 is greyed out.

What additional packages does Amarok need in order to enable the transcode to MP3 option?

Oh, the "Amarok DIagnostics" output, from the Help menu gives:

Amarok Diagnostics

```
Amarok Version: 2.6.0
KDE Version: 4.9.3
Qt Version: 4.8.2
Phonon Version: 4.6.0
Phonon Backend: GStreamer (4.6.2)
PulseAudio: Yes

Amarok Scripts:
    Amarok Script Console 1.0 (stopped)
Discogs 1.1b (stopped)
Lyricwiki .2 (stopped)
Free Music Charts 1.6.0 (stopped)
Librivox.org 1.0 (stopped)
Cool Streams 1.0 (stopped)
BBC 1.1 (stopped)

Amarok Plugins:
    AudioCd Collection (enabled)
DAAP Collection (enabled)
MTP Collection (enabled)
MySQLServer Collection (enabled)
MySQLe Collection (enabled)
UPnP Collection (enabled)
Universal Mass Storage Collection (enabled)
iPod, iPad & iPhone Collection (enabled)
Ampache (disabled)
Jamendo (disabled)
Last.fm (enabled)
MP3 Music Store (disabled)
MP3tunes (disabled)
Magnatune Store (disabled)
Podcast Directory (enabled)
gpodder.net (enabled)
Local Files & USB Mass Storage Backend (enabled)
NFS Share Backend (enabled)
SMB (Windows) Share Backend (enabled)
```

Comment: Do you have gstreamer and Kubuntu-restricted-extras installed?

Comment: @iSeth--I have the following gstreamer packages installed:  
    - gstreamer0.10-alsa  
    - gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg  
    - gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3  
    - gstreamer0.10-nice  
    - gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad  
    - gstreamer0.10-plugins-base  
    - gstreamer0.10-plugins-good  
    - gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly  
    - gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio  
- gstreamer0.10-qapt  
- gstreamer0.10-x  
- libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0  
- libgstreamer0.10-0  
- libqtgstreamer-0.10-0  
- phonon-backend-gstreamer  
If I try to install kubuntu-restricted-extras, a whole heap of packages would be removed...